# VUE does not load page content when compiling

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a program made in VUE that works for me locally but stops working when compiling.

The idea is that within the initial VUE App.vue file I load content from other files, in this case the Home.vue file

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app color="primary" dark>
      V.4.0
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
       2022  
    </v-app-bar>
    
    <v-main>
      <router-view/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
};
```

The **index.js** of the routes

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: function () {
      return import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/Home.vue')
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/llistat',
    name: 'Llistat',
    component: function () {
      return import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/Llistat_feina.vue')
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
</script>
```

the **Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-container>
      <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
    <router-link to="/Llistat">1. Llistat</router-link><br>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  

  export default {
    name: 'Home',

    components: {
    },
  }
</script>
```

If I run it locally it works fine. Load the App.vue, find the path and insert the Home.vue

[image]

If I compile it and upload it to the server, it does not load the content of Home.vue, it only loads the code of App.vue

[image]

Any idea what might be going on? Thanks

Comment: One issue I see is the chunk name is the same for two routes (`"about"`). Is that just a copy-paste error in the question?

Comment: This is a comment from VUE, "about" is not used

Comment: That comment tells Webpack how to name the chunks. You'll see this filename in your build output.

Comment: I removed the code / * webpackChunkName: "about" * / but the error persists.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must configure your web server to serve `index.html` for all non-existent filenames instead of returning HTTP status code 404 - or to switch your VueRouter to `hash` mode instead of `history`. You must also properly set `publicPath` in `vue.config.js` and `base` in VueRouter - they must be the same and reflect the folder on the web server where your Vue application is being served from.

Comment: Removing mode: 'history', from the routes index.js, works. Although the URL is not as I want

Comment: If you need pretty URLs then you must configure the web server to serve `index.html` for all inexistent URL paths/locations. No other way.